# jQuery ID Return is undefined although HTML ID is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to retrieve the ID of one element, store it as a variable and then use that ID value to interact with other elements in that section with the same ID.

```
<div class="mainContent">
<div class="articleContent">
     <h1>header1</h1>
     <p class="articlePara" id="one">para1</p>
</div>
<div class="articleFooter" id="one" onclick="readMore()">
</div>
</div>

<div class="mainContent">
<div class="articleContent">
     <h1>header2</h1>
     <p class="articlePara" id="two">para2</p>
</div>
<div class="articleFooter" id="two" onclick="readMore()">
</div>
</div>
```

And then the JS/jQuery

```
function readMore() {
var subID = event.target.id;

var newTarget = document.getElementById(subID).getElementsByClassName("articlePara");

alert(newTarget.id);
}
```

At this point I'm only trying to display the ID of the selected element but it is returning undefined and in most cases people seem to notice that jQuery is getting confused because of the differences between DOM variables and jQuery ones.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dr0f2nu3/

To be completely clear, I want to be able to click on one element, retrieve the ID and then select an element in the family of that clicked element using that ID value.

Comment: @prasad answer your question. But, fact remains that you should not have more than one same id in your html. (ref. id = "one")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove the `getElementsByClassName("articlePara");` in end of the `newTarget` .already you are call the element with `id` alert the element of the id is same with `target.id`

```js
function readMore() {
  var subID = event.target.id;
  var newTarget = $('[id='+subID+'][class="articlePara"]')
console.log(newTarget.attr('id'));
console.log(newTarget.length);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainContent">
  <div class="articleContent">
    <h1>header</h1>
    <p class="articlePara" id="one"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="articleFooter" id="one" onclick="readMore()">click
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But then it won't be selecting the paragraph, it'll be selecting both elements with ID="subID", I'm trying to make it so that it runs for every article element interchangeably regardless of the value of "subID"

Comment: @PaulMcGlinchey see the updated answer. I was add the code for find all element of the id="subId" .see the console its show no of element contain same id

Comment: Okay, nice but how do I traverse between those 2 elements? That's why I was using `getElementsByClassName("articlePara")`

Comment: You should **not** have two elements with the same ID in the same HTML document.

Comment: @LegendaryJLD Well even alternatively, say I'm using classes instead of IDs. After selecting the class "group" that I've created, how would I then select the individual paragraph so that I can display it's ID or format it using JS?

Comment: Thank you! Been looking at this for hours now. Anywhere I could read up on this `$('[id='+subID+'][class="articlePara"]')` , I've never seen it anywhere before @prasad

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.articleFooter').click(function() { 
        var b=subId; //can be any 
        var a="p[id="+b+"]"+"[class='articlePara']";
        $(a).something;
    });
```

Comment: Because, again, this would only retrieve the ID of a collection of elements with the class .articlePara whereas I have already defined the ID as "one" and now wish to select that specific paragraph, as alternatively to select all of the paragraphs with the class .articlePara

Comment: So you want to select `<p>` having class `.articlePara` and having `id=one`. Is it? @PaulMcGlinchey

Comment: Yes, except the id="subID", not "one". The ID is interchangeable depending on the article. Check my updated post for better representation of this.

Answer (score 0):

As you have read before, you should keep your id's unique, and you should avoid using onclick in html, but you could do it like this.

With querySelector you get the element and then with parentElement you can retrieve the parent of that element.

```
function readMore(el) {
  var articleFooterId = el.id;
  var articlePara = document.querySelector(".articleContent #"+articleFooterId);
  var articleContent = articlePara.parentElement;

  console.log('articleFooter', articleFooterId);
  console.log('articlePara', articlePara);
  console.log('articleContent', articleContent);
}
```

In your html you can return the 'this' object back to the function by doing readMore(this).

```
<div class="mainContent">
  <div class="articleContent">
       <h1>header1</h1>
       <p class="articlePara" id="one">para1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="articleFooter" id="one" onclick="readMore(this)">footertext</div>
</div>

<div class="mainContent">
  <div class="articleContent">
       <h1>header2</h1>
       <p class="articlePara" id="two">para2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="articleFooter" id="two" onclick="readMore(this)">footertext</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr0f2nu3/)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('div.articleFooter').click(function () {
        var para = $(this).prev().find('p.articlePara').text();
        alert('T:' + para);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have forgotten to pass in `event` as parameter in your `onclick=` call in html.
2. In your javascript, you need to include `event` in the parenthesis as well.

   ```
   window.readMore = function(event) {...}
   ```
3. if you write `document.getElementById(subID).getElementsByClassName("articlePara");` That's saying you want to get your clicked element's **CHILD** elements that have `class` equal to `articlePara` . There is none. So you get undefined.

   If you want to find all element with a ID `one` and a class `articlePara`, it can be done easily with jQuery:

   ```
   newtarget = $("#one.articlePara");
   ```

You can insert a line: `debugger;` in your onclick handler function to trigger the browser's debugging tool and inspect the values of variables. Then you will know whether you are getting what you want.